# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I'm trying to use GeoAdmin in GeoDjango.
I have a table planet_osm_point and I would like to see it in the admin interface.
I'm a beginner in django.

I have this problem :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/api/planetosmpoint/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.gis',
 'api',
 'portail')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html, error at line 91
   'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
   81 :         {% endif %}


   82 :       {% endblock %}


   83 : 


   84 :       <form id="changelist-form" action="" method="post"{% if cl.formset.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>{% csrf_token %}


   85 :       {% if cl.formset %}


   86 :         <div>{{ cl.formset.management_form }}</div>


   87 :       {% endif %}


   88 : 


   89 :       {% block result_list %}


   90 :           {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}


   91 :            {% result_list cl %} 


   92 :           {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}


   93 :       {% endblock %}


   94 :       {% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}


   95 :       </form>


   96 :     </div>


   97 :   </div>


   98 : {% endblock %}


   99 : 

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  140.                     response = response.render()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  82.         content = template.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  124.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  124.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  63.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  63.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1185.                     _dict = func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in result_list
  286.             'results': list(results(cl))}
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in results
  264.             yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in __init__
  256.         super(ResultList, self).__init__(*items)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in items_for_result
  184.             f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py" in lookup_field
  258.                 value = attr()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __str__
  433.             return force_text(self).encode('utf-8')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/api/planetosmpoint/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I have # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- at the top of my files.
Can you explain me how to debug this ?

Best regards
Etienne

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a model class whose `__unicode__` method is returning `None`.

Make sure it actually has a `return` statement that returns a Unicode value instead.

Answer (score 1):

return str(self.model_attribute)   for the unicode