# python-How to save html pages as pdf?

Tags: python, html, pdf

I've tried `pdfkit` but couldn't solve this [issue](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/issues/123).

I wonder whether there is any alternatives?
Or other method to save a webpage as a pdf file?

**EDIT**

I tried to use `xhtml2pdf` under @lqbal's suggestion.
It did work **only when I remove the google fonts used in the html**. -See [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654263/django-xhtml2pdf-object-has-no-attribute-encode)

However, without those fonts, the web page would be in a terrible format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import time
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import StringIO
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
import sys 
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import * 

url = 'http://www.yahoo.com'
tem_pdf = "c:\\tem_pdf.pdf"
final_file = "c:\\younameit.pdf"

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
#Read the URL given
web.load(QUrl(url))
printer = QPrinter()
#setting format
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
printer.setOrientation(QPrinter.Landscape)
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
#export file as c:\tem_pdf.pdf
printer.setOutputFileName(tem_pdf)

def convertIt():
    web.print_(printer)
    QApplication.exit()

QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), convertIt)

app.exec_()
sys.exit

# Below is to add on the weblink as text and present date&time on PDF generated

outputPDF = PdfFileWriter()
packet = StringIO.StringIO()
# create a new PDF with Reportlab
can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
can.setFont("Helvetica", 9)
# Writting the new line
oknow = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M")
can.drawString(5, 2, url)
can.drawString(605, 2, oknow)
can.save()

#move to the beginning of the StringIO buffer
packet.seek(0)
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
# read your existing PDF
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(file(tem_pdf, "rb"))
pages = existing_pdf.getNumPages()
output = PdfFileWriter()
# add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
for x in range(0,pages):
    page = existing_pdf.getPage(x)
    page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
    output.addPage(page)
# finally, write "output" to a real file
outputStream = file(final_file, "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()

print final_file, 'is ready.'
```

Comment: It seems that I'll have to install several other package it run this script. Is it possible to simplify it cuz what I'm trying to implement is quite a small project and I really don't want to make it complicated. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion and if there aren't any better solution I'll try it. :)